# AttributeError related to multiprocessing when using extract_features from tsfresh

Tags: python, multiprocessing, feature-extraction

I have a data frame which contains multivariate time series data. It has columns: fundId (each entity), periodId(time stamp), v1,  v2, v3 ...

I want to extract features from those times series for each fund over time. Like: fundId v1.max, v1.min, v1.median, ..., v2.max, v2.min, v2.median, ...

I encountered an AttributeError when use function extract_features from library tsfresh. I'm new to Python but I think it might related to multiprocessing.

The trackback shows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "", line 1, in 
    HFeatures = extract_features(FundCharc, column_id='fundId', column_sort='periodId')

File "mypath\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\extraction.py", line 178, in extract_features
    distributor=distributor)

File "mypath\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction\extraction.py", line 313, in _do_extraction
    progressbar_title="Feature Extraction")

File "mypath\lib\site-packages\tsfresh\utilities\distribution.py", line 349, in **init**
    self.pool = Pool(processes=n_workers)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 176, in **init**
    self._repopulate_pool()

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 241, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 33, in **init**
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 172, in get_preparation_data
    main_mod_name = getattr(main_module.**spec**, "name", None)

AttributeError: module '**main**' has no attribute '**spec**'

```py
from tsfresh import extract_features
HFeatures = extract_features(FundCharc, column_id='fundId', column_sort='periodId')
```